# Clear Chrome file system data for all sites?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has a [file system API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) that seems to persist through normal clearing of the cache, etc.

*(Side note: It essentially seems like a built-in "supercookie" facility. Security implications?)*

I know I can go and manually delete the files "out-of-band", but is there a "proper" way to clear this data for all websites at once from inside Chrome?